# Pivot Data with Uneven Groups Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a table and I want to convert it using Python 3x Pandas into the following:

| Group | Assessment | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GroupA | No team spirit | Negative |
| GroupA | Good players | Positive |
| GroupA | They scored well | Positive |
| GroupB | Goal failed | Negative |
| GroupB | Bad weather | Negative |
| GroupB | Resilience | Positive |
| GroupB | Growth potential | Positive |
| GroupB | Bad technique | Negative |

Resulting table should be:

| Group | Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GroupA | Good players | No team spirit |
| GroupA | They scored well | NaN |
| GroupB | Resilience | Goal Failed |
| GroupB | Growth Potential | Bad weather |
| GroupB | NaN | Bad Technique |

Is there any neat, Pythonic way of doing it using Pandas or other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `pivot` as is, but you could add a group number using `groupby` + `cumcount` and `pivot` using the newly created numbering as index:

```
out = (df.assign(num=df.groupby(['Group','Review']).cumcount())
       .pivot(['num','Group'],'Review','Assessment')
       .droplevel(0).sort_index()
       [['Positive','Negative']]
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

Output:

```
    Group          Positive        Negative
0  GroupA      Good players  No team spirit
1  GroupA  They scored well             NaN
2  GroupB        Resilience     Goal failed
3  GroupB  Growth potential     Bad weather
4  GroupB               NaN   Bad technique
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what the "num=" parameters serves for in the assign method?

Comment: @matt.aurelio it's creating a new column named "num", which we use to pivot

Answer (score 0):

it is not what you exactly want, but it seems this table structure has more sence:

```
res = (df.groupby(['Group','Review']).
       apply(lambda x:x['Assessment'].tolist()).
       unstack())
print(res)
'''
Review                                   Negative                          Positive
Group                                                                              
GroupA                           [No team spirit]  [Good players, They scored well]
GroupB  [Goal failed, Bad weather, Bad technique]    [Resilience, Growth potential]
```